# Is it possible to highlight an annotation and its related geometry with CATIA VBA?

Tags: vba, catia

Im asking this because I feel like I've searched the internet but can't quite get the answer I'm looking for. Im trying to highlight an annotation and its related geometry(surface) through a VBA macro but I can't find a clear way to do it.

I know 2 ways to highlight an annotation and its related geometry in CATIA itself and tried to implement it into my code, but it doesn't work the way I want it to.

1. Using the 3D Annotation Query Switch ON/Switch Off [3D Annotation Command Icon in CATIA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JE9cq.png)

This highlights the annotation and its related geometry; HOWEVER, it will also highlight all other annotations that are connected to the geometry. Which I don't want.

2. Using Highlighting Geometry [Highlighting Geometry Command Icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z9bKZ.png)

This will highlight an annotations related geometry with user interaction by having the user select an annotation. This does what I want but if I use `CATIA.StartCommand` and then `CATIA.ActiveDocument.Selection.Search` it doesnt work. I think it needs the user to actually select something. I also want to avoid `CATIA.StartCommand` as I want to be able to use the macro in multiple languages.

Is there any other commands I can use or a way to find the surface through the annotation?